# Passing the id of closest element as a parameter value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a few parameters passed on to a js function (I'm using jeditable).

```
$('.edit_area').editable('update.php',{
id      : '2',
type      : 'textarea'
});
```

> .edit_area is a `<p>` element. I need the value of 'id' passed as the
>   value of the closest parent `<div>` element.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one `.edit_area` element in the page

```
$('.edit_area').editable('update.php', {
    id: $('.edit_area').closest('div').att('id'),
    type: 'textarea'
});
```

If you have multiple elements

```
$('.edit_area').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.editable('update.php', {
        id: $this..closest('div').att('id'),
        type: 'textarea'
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the first div in the hierarcy of parents.

```
$('.edit_area').editable('update.php',{
   id    : $('.edit_area').closest('div').attr('id'),
   type  : 'textarea'
});
```

**[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the 
>    element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#2').parents('div:eq(0)').attr('id');  //where 2 is your param
```